# TypeScript - overloads function problem with same interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I really want to understand the logic of TypeScript in this situation it's not clear to me.

Main questions:

- How to fix it
- Why it is doesn't work

**Code example:**

```
enum Type {
    one = 'one',
    two = 'two',
}

function first(type: Type.one): number;
function first(type: Type.two): string;
function first(type: Type.one | Type.two): number | string | boolean {
    if (type === Type.one) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (type === Type.two) {
        return '2';
    }

    return false;
}

// Function with the same interface which calls first function
function second(type: Type.one): number;
function second(type: Type.two): string;
function second(type: Type.one | Type.two): number | string | boolean {
    const firstResult = first(type); // -> No overload matches this call.

    // ...do something with firstResult

    if (type === Type.one) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (type === Type.two) {
        return '2';
    }

    return false;
}

const result1 = second(Type.one);
const result2 = second(Type.two);
```

**What I expect:** no type issues because the interface is the same

**What I got:** "No overload matches this call" for this line:

```
const firstResult = first(type);
```

Comment: I think this is the root issue - no clean solutions https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107

Comment: If you want to be able to call `first()` with a parameter of type `Type.one | Type.two` you need to add a call signature that conforms to it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9AZjN).  If that works for you I'll write up an answer; otherwise the answer is as @aacotroneo says: there's an open feature request for the compiler to resolve multiple call signatures at once.

Comment: Oh, seems like it works for me! Thanks